# Slow compiling swift source file - Xcode 8 swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dictionary, swift3

I have just updated my project to `Xcode 8` and `Swift 3`. 
My problem is that my app is very very slow to compile a specific class, the following:

```
var dict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        return [
            "book_key": book_key as AnyObject,
            "book_title": book_title as AnyObject,
            "book_author": book_author as AnyObject,
            "book_price": book_price as AnyObject,
            "book_publisher" : book_publisher as AnyObject,
            "page_count": page_count as AnyObject,
            "book_description": book_description as AnyObject,
            "book_urlImage" : book_urlImage as AnyObject,
            "book_urlImage2": book_urlImage2 as AnyObject,
            "user_key": user_key as AnyObject,
            "user_name": user_name as AnyObject,
            "user_tag_login" : user_tag_login as AnyObject,
            "onGoingNegotiations" : onGoingNegotiations as AnyObject,
            "other_user_key": other_user_key as AnyObject,
            "other_tag_login": other_tag_login as AnyObject,
            "book_condition": book_condition as AnyObject,
            "timestamp": timestamp! as AnyObject
        ]
    }
```

How can I resolve my problem? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Convert your dictionary into a class (object) might be easier since you have all these properties (book_key, book_title...etc)

Comment: use `ObjectMapper`:just a suggestion

Comment: Thanks @PeterLee, It is better. With Xcode 7 was faster than now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is so slowly and so I have found the solution. 
The `timestamp` NSNumber will be cast as `String` and so the method works perfectly again.

```
 var dict: Dictionary<String, String> {
        return [
            "book_key": book_key,
            "book_title": book_title,
            "book_author": book_author,
            "book_price": book_price,
            "book_publisher" : book_publisher,
            "page_count": page_count,
            "book_description": book_description,
            "book_urlImage" : book_urlImage,
            "book_urlImage2": book_urlImage2,
            "user_key": user_key,
            "user_name": user_name,
            "user_tag_login" : user_tag_login,
            "onGoingNegotiations" : onGoingNegotiations,
            "other_user_key": other_user_key,
            "other_tag_login": other_tag_login,
            "book_condition": book_condition,
            "timestamp": timestamp
        ]
}
```

Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3** like this:

if it is of several types

```
var dict: [String: Any] = [
                "book_key":    true,
                "book_title":  "Yannick",
                "book_author": "Test",
                "book_price":  123
            ]
```

Or if you return lot of String like this

```
var dict: [String: String] = [
                "book_key":       "true",
                "book_author":    "Yannick",
                "book_price":     "123",
                "book_publisher": "Yannick",
                "page_count":     "123"
            ]
```